# sql php code igniter retrieve data from one table which has uncommon id with other table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables

Table1

```
ID   :  1        2       3       4       5    6    7

NAME :  abc     abcd    abcde   xy      xyz  lmn    lmno
```

Table2

```
ID   :  1        2       3       4     

NAME :  abc     abcd    abcde   xy
```

How can I get the following

```
ID   :   5    6    7

NAME :  xyz  lmn    lmno
```

Comment: read this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1):

This sql-statement is your solution:

```
select id,name from Table1 where id not in (select id from Table2)
```